# Problems animating an Android layout; elements snap back to start position

Tags: android, animation, android-relativelayout

I have been searching for an answer to this for days, and while some things *kinda* work (and most don't), I'm hoping I can find the best practice for what I'm trying to do.

I'm trying to get a notification bar to display in my app. Ideally, it would slide down from the top, while shifting other elements in the layout to accommodate. Here's an illustration to help: [illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5X64a.jpg)

Here is how the layout is structured (I took out a bit for brevity):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <!-- notification -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/notification_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:background="@drawable/notification_background"
        android:visibility="visible">

    <!-- end notifcation -->    
    </RelativeLayout> 

    <!-- header -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="47dip"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header_bg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="47dip"
            android:src="@drawable/home_header" />

    <!-- end header -->    
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- buttons -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@id/notification_bar"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:src="@drawable/button1"
        android:layout_width="86dip"
        android:layout_height="65dip"
        android:layout_weight=".4" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:src="@drawable/button2"
        android:layout_width="98dip"
        android:layout_height="73dip"
        android:layout_weight=".2" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:src="@drawable/button3"
        android:layout_width="86dip"
        android:layout_height="71dip"
            android:layout_weight=".4" />

<!-- end buttons -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- footer -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="76dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/home_footer" >

    <!-- end footer -->
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MAIN PROBLEM:
To start, I animated the notification bar.  It moves, and at the end of the animation, it *snaps back into place*.  Yes, I have fillAfter set to true.  It doesn't make a difference.  Regardless, the 3 items that should shift are clickable, and from what I've read, the elements haven't *actually* moved, they just *look* like they have.

SECONDARY PROBLEM:
The entire view is a RelativeLayout, however the three elements are in a LinearLayout set via the XML to be layout_below the notification bar.  I had hoped that shifting the notification bar would *squeeze* this LinearLayout, shifting the buttons to accommodate, but no such luck. If I have to shift the three elements as separate animations, that's fine.  I've tried that, but they suffer from the same "snap-back" issue the notification bar does.  I was hoping there would be a simpler, more logical approach, however.

I've found a number of posts about this snap-back problem, but none of the solutions quite work (or make sense to me, granted a bit of a noob). It sounds like something needs to happen in the onAnimationEnd handler. I think it's something with adjusting the LayoutParams, but I'm not sure how or what to do there.

I'm targeting for API 8 (2.2), so the Honeycomb animation APIs won't help.  I've looked into NineOldAndroids, which looks promising, but figure there has *got* to be a way to do this with the native API.

** Bonus points if we can get the notification bar to be dismissed, and everything moves back to its original position.

** UPDATE: The following code KIND OF works **

Here is the animation method to slide the notification bar out:

```
private void showNotification() {

    mNotificationBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    Animation slideOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,  R.anim.slide_notification_out);

    slideOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
             // do SOMETHING
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mNotificationBar.getLayoutParams();
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, mHeader.getId());

            mNotificationBar.setLayoutParams(params);
            mNotificationBar.clearAnimation();

        }
    });

    mNotificationBar.startAnimation(slideOut);  
}
```

Altering the LayoutParams on AnimationEnd keeps the Notification bar in place.  AND, when the animation is done, the Buttons layout squeezes to accommodate!  BUT, the button layout doesn't smoothly animate like the Notification Bar, it just snaps into place at the end of the animation.  Also, the Notification Bar also jumps a bit at the very end of the animation, I'm guessing because the layout is being redrawn. SO CLOSE, but so far.

Comment: didn't see a line of code : didn't read at all.

Comment: I thought I was being specific enough; didn't realize that was a "requirement." Thanks for the comment, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Snap back problem`

You need to define the notification in the final place that you want it to appear in the layout. For you it's probably as the first item in the `LinearLayout` you refer above. Then you set `visibility`to `gone`.

Finally you use a piece of code similar to the one bellow (I´m using it to animate buttons into the screen):

```
private void buttonFadeOut() {
        linear_layout_buttons.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MyMapActivity.this, android.R.anim.slide_out_right));
        linear_layout_buttons.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}


private void buttonFadeIn() {
    if(linear_layout_buttons.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
        linear_layout_buttons.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MyMapActivity.this, R.anim.slide_in_right));
        linear_layout_buttons.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

`Squeeze problem`

This one I've never tried with an animation, but you can set the `android:layout_weight="1.0"` in each one of the items in your relative layout, to split the available space equaly between them (or play with the value to assign diferent space for each).

Regards.

Comment: Thanks Luis. I've tried animation code similar to (if not exactly like) this. Perhaps it has something to do with how I structured my XML.  I have tried defining the notification in it's final place (below the header) and at it's starting place (hidden behind the header).  I still get the snap back problem.

Comment: Are you sure you set the visibility to `View.GONE` and `View.VISIBLE` exactly as as I'm showing above? That should solve the snap back problem.

Comment: I added some code to hopefully shine some more light on the situation.  I tried to not modify the view visibility at all; it shouldn't be necessary.  The notification bar is hidden behind the header when it's up. The problem was that, when the animation is done, and the notification bar is in its final down position where it should stay, it snaps back behind the header instead.

Comment: I believe you didn't understood how animation works. When you have a slide in animation, it always start from one side of the screen (depending on animation type) and always ends in the position where it's defined on the layout. So, if it's defined hidden behind the header, that will be the position where it will be after the end of animation. That's also the reason why you realy need to change visibility. Visibility starts `GONE` (so notification is not there), you start animation (this gives you the effect of moving) and after you set visibilty to `VISIBLE` (to have it on shown on screen)

Comment: YES! Now I get it! (Despite it being extremely counter-intuitive!) Thank you, Luis.

Comment: Still have to work out the Squeeze problem...  But hopefully armed with how the animations truly work I will make some progress there.