# Swipe animation starting on button click

Tags: android, android-animation

I need to implement swipe animation in android. I've looked at [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) example, but the problem is that I need to start animation on button click and do nothing on swipes. Is it posible to implement in some easy way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very generic. Have a look at my answer on this post: [Problems animating an Android layout; elements snap back to start position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352534/problems-animating-an-android-layout-elements-snap-back-to-start-position/13353471#13353471)

You can call the methods I gave as example within button ´OnClick()`.

Regards.

Comment: It was enough for me to discover that android has default slide animations `android.R.anim.slide_in_left` and `android.R.anim.slide_out_right`. Thanks!